# Doctrine/Inheritance cannot check if a child of X is instanceof Y

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a trouble to get specific types of object from my database. I have several entities in my hierarchy like below:

I have an abstract class called `Action` with `@ORM\MappedSuperclass`

Then I have others classes which extends `Action`: `UserAction, PictureAction, VideoAction`, all of these with the same ORM tag MappedSuperclass.

Finally I have truly entity classes: `UserLikeAction, PictureCommentAction, VideoCreateAction`, which extends respectively `UserAction, PictureAction, VideoAction`.

In my controller, I want to get user activity represented by theses Action subclasses by using a DQL query:

`SELECT a FROM AppBundle:Action a WHERE a.user = :logged_user AND a INSTANCE OF AppBundle:UserLikeAction`

Symfony2 returns me this exception message: 
`Cannot check if a child of '...\Action' is instanceof '...\UserLikeAction', inheritance hierarchy exists between these two classes.`

For the use case, I want to show a timeline of all my likes.

How can I fix this?

Thanks for reading and your help!

Comment: Do you have a discriminator map?

Comment: I don't think so, what is it?

Comment: Might want to review the single table inheritance docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html.  I think you just need SELECT a FROM AppBundle:UserLikeAction but I suspect you have other issues based on your discriminator comment.

Comment: Without discriminator map doctrine doesn't know which table entry is which php type